# service worker - best way to determine if client is a mobile device

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am working on a service worker in the `fetch` event and am wondering the best way to determine if the client is a mobile device knowing that `userAgent` can be inconsistent now days.

I've looked at `self.navigator` and didn't see anything that would give this info to me other than `userAgent`. I also tried looking the the `WindowClient` array and there seems to be no indications there either.

Comment: What qualifies as a mobile device? Should it have a sim card? Touch screen? A battery? I think you should focus on the device capabilities, not what kind of device it is.

Comment: @StephanVierkant Very good question. I need to know if it was touch screen. Normally I would get this via navigator.maxTouchpoints, however this is not available in the service worker navigator.

Comment: Why do you need that information in the service worker?

Comment: @StephanVierkant In my fetch event I look for a specific query param on get requests and navigation events. If the request is coming from a mobile device I need to handle the request as normal, otherwise I respond with a redirect response.

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider this approach, because that means a 90" touch device (yes, they exist) gets the 'mobile' response? It depends on your use case, maybe another device capability (Network speed? Battery powered?) suits better. Otherwise, save the device type/mode in a cookie/local storage?

Comment: @StephanVierkant thanks you got me thinking of a different approach. I decided to pass a value into the service worker registration as a query param

Answer (score 2):

This feels like a [X&Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/242284). Because what qualifies as a mobile device? And I think that's a question that can't be answered.

I've got 2 laptops with a touch screen (which I hate to use), a 10" tablet (with a keyboard dock and bluetooth mouse), I've got a 65" touch screen (no mouse or keyboard) in my office and my car has a Chrome browser. That device is (according to Android) not battery powered. My mobile phone (when on 5G) has the fastest internet connection of them all. One of my laptops is the slowest device I have. Which devices are mobile? I don't know. So [using a browser agent is usually a bad idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/JavaScript#using_bad_browser_sniffing_code).

You want to see if a device is a mobile device in the service worker, but the service worker works in the background and there's no screen involved. So you can't use it, but even if you could, you shouldn't.

Instead of 'What kind of device is this?' you should ask 'Is this device capable of doing X?' That method is called [Feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) or 'progressive enhancement'.

As a workaround you can store some information (screen size, touch screen) somewhere (cookie, local storage) and use it in your service worker, but it might be a better idea to focus on what makes a 'mobile' different from a 'non-mobile' device instead.